# Knockout ViewModel observable variable combine with computed

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js, eval

I'm playing around with Knockout.js for data-binding quite a long time. But, got stuck with this problem. Actually, its a enhancement i'm trying to do.

Now I'm trying to do this,

- I've a observable variable in my VM
- I've a Math equation for each observable variable
- Every time model updated, before it reach to view, variable should be computed with equation and set result on View.

Currently, i'm taking three variable to get my job done.

```
var variable = 'x01'; 
//vm - is object of my view model.
vm[variable] = ko.observable(24.8);
vm["+variable+"_conversion"] = "X * 10 - 248"; 
vm[""+variable+"_computed"] = ko.computed(function() {
    val_ac = vm[variable]();
    ac = vm[""+variable+"_conversion"];
    var X = val_ac;
    return eval(ac);
},vm);
```

To update model:

```
vm[variable] = 25;
```

Since, all my views are custom handlers. I'mr eading data as below:

```
value = vm[""+variable+"_computed"]();
```

But, here im using two variables (Though second one will not hold data but function). How can i merge all above three variables into one?

May be something like this;

```
vm[variable] = ko.computed(function(X){
    var ac="X * 10 - 276";
    return eval(ac);
},vm);
vm[variable](26);   // --this should set data to model and trigger observers 
val = vm[variable]; // --this should get data to set to view
```

Any other better possibilities or improvement suggestions are welcome !

**Edit: Adding [Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/m26dsxbf/3/)**

My Question in above link is as follows:

- var1, var2 are variable holders
- var1_computed, var2_computed are computed holders

How can i use only one set of variables (var1,var2 / var1_computed,var2_computed) for both data holder and computations and avoid multiple variables.

It may not make much difference in fiddle example. My application logic handles 1600 variables, which will be updated at 10 sec interval. So, i should be vary careful about memory consumption.

Comment: can you reproduce the issue in a working example like jsfiddle or stack snippet please?

Comment: It _sounds_ like you want a [Writable Computed](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-writable.html), but yes - as @Tanner says, more info would be useful.

Comment: @JamesThorpe updated my question. can you have a glance at it now.